# Why Do 137 Electron-Positron Pairs In Their Compton Wavelength Have Electrostatic Potential About Equal The Mass Energy of One Pair?

Tags: potential-energy, dimensional-analysis, mass-energy, perturbation-theory, pair-production

Why does taking the ratio of the mass energy of an electron positron pair to their electrostatic potential energy at their Compton wavelength yield a number very close to $\alpha^{-1} \approx 137$:

$$137 \approx \frac{2 m_e c^2}{\frac{k_e e^2 2 m_e  c}{\hbar}}=\frac{k_ee^2}{\hbar c}=\frac{e^2}{4\pi\epsilon_0 \hbar c}=\alpha^{-1}$$

One interpretation is that 137 pairs may be packed into that small of a space without pair production draining potential energy, but 138 would be an unstable count.  While [I suspect this has something to do with](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/613926/3673) Freeman Dyson's argument in "[Divergence of Perturbation Theory in Quantum Electrodynamics](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRev.85.631)", there the count is of the number of terms of summation (perhaps related to [Borel resummation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel_summation)) -- not energy density or pair production therefrom.

Answer (score 2):

This should not come as a surprise since
the [fine-structure constant is defined](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fine-structure_constant#Definition) by
$$\alpha=\frac{k_ee^2}{\hbar c}$$
where $k_e=\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}$ is [Coulomb's constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coulomb%27s_law#Coulomb_constant).

Comment: I edited the question to focus on the physical interpretation in the context of Dyson's counting argument rather than the trivial algebraic relation you pointed out.